Agent variable is not resolved in 'if' condition in deployment job in template
Agent.MachineName variable is not resolved in 'if' condition in self-hosted deployment job template.
${{ if eq(s_t.resource, 'VM000000001') }}:

works fine, but
${{ if eq(s_t.resource, variables['Agent.MachineName']) }}:

does not work.
The template:
parameters:
- name: stage_name
  type: string
- name: azure_environment
  type: string
- name: depends_on_stage
  type: string
- name: startup_types
  type: object

# Usage:
# ...    
# startup_types:
# - resource: VM000000001
#   startup_type: Manual
#   start_service: false
# - resource: VM000000002
#   startup_type: Manual
#   start_service: false

stages:
- stage: ${{ parameters.stage_name }}
  dependsOn: ${{ parameters.depends_on_stage }}
  jobs:
  - deployment: ${{ parameters.stage_name }}
    workspace:
      clean: all
    environment: 
      name: ${{ parameters.azure_environment }}
      resourceType: VirtualMachine
    variables:
      ${{ each s_t in parameters.startup_types }}:
        # ${{ if eq(s_t.resource, variables['Agent.MachineName']) }}: # <=== Not working
        ${{ if eq(s_t.resource, 'VM000000001') }}:
          startup_type_resource: ${{ s_t.resource }}
          startup_type: ${{ s_t.startup_type }}
          start_service: ${{ s_t.start_service }}
    strategy:
      ...

With the nested each-if expression my intention is to select the startup type that belongs to the actual deployment agent.

If any of the below answers help you, please consider upvoting them and maybe accepting one as the correct answer?

The template expression "${{ xxxx }}" is evaluated at compile-time before runtime. However, not all the predefined variables are available in template expression. Because some predefined variables are evaluated are runtime.
See "Template expressions".

In the documentation "Use predefined variables", only the predefined variables which are stated as "Yes" for "Available in templates?" can be available in template expression.

If the predefined variables are stated as "No" for "Available in templates?", or not stated, they are not available in template expression.



You're mixing template expressions with runtime variables:
${{ if eq(s_t.resource, variables['Agent.MachineName']) }}


${{ if ... }} is a template expression that is compiled when you queue a new build.

Agent variables such as Agent.MachineName are available at runtime, and will be set after an agent is assigned to a job waiting in the queue of an agent pool.


Workaround
Consider configuring capabilities (user-defined or system capabilities) to your build agents running on VM000000001 and VM000000002:

You can then use the capabilities as build variables in your pipeline - example:
- script: |
    echo "$(AgentCapabilities.User.startup_type)"
    echo "$(AgentCapabilities.User.start_service)"
  displayName: Display user capabilities

